# TSQL query for "accumulated value"

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cumulative-sum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate a Running Total in SqlServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver)

I am new to SQL. This question seems very basic but I just couldn't find the answer, maybe I am not hitting the right keyword.

In SQL server 2008 R2 I have a table like this:

```
Date      Value
---------------
2012-1-1    100
2012-1-2     50
2012-1-4    200
```

I want to create a view with accumulated value, like this:

```
Date      Total
---------------
2012-1-1    100
2012-1-2    150
2012-1-4    350
```

How should I do it?

Comment: @KenWhite, thanks for the info, it is exactly what I'm looking for. But please do not presume I didn't try searching. As a non-English speaker and new to SQL, I tried every word I could think of including "rollup", "accumulated", "historical sum", etc. I guess since I've realized this, my question should have really been "what is the terminology for [this thingy] in SQL world".

Comment: You're absolutely correct - I should not have made that presumption. I saw `running-total` in the tag, and made the assumption (and we all know what that means) that you had put it there. My apologies. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get the running total. try this one:

```
SELECT dateHere,
       total,
       total + COALESCE(
                         (
                            SELECT SUM(total)
                            FROM myTable b
                            WHERE b.dateHere < a.dateHere
                          ), 0) AS RunningTotal
FROM     myTable a
ORDER BY dateHere
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20257/1)

Comment: Can I use this as view definition? I got SQL execution error: Incorrect syntax near ‘ORDERBY'. (I replaced "myTable" with "dbo.MyTable")

Comment: `ORDERBY` must be written as two separate words `ORDER BY`. Surely you can create a view on this.

Comment: can you post your new query? be sure to change the columns with your own columnNames.

Comment: Yup ORDERBY was the issue. Rookie mistake. Thanks for the answer and being patient with me:)

Comment: No problem. You are welcome NS :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.date, t.value,
       (select sum(t2.value)
        from t t2
        where t2.date <= t.date
       ) as cumvalue
from t
```